# Android x86 9.0 Ethernet Connection on Physical Machine

Tags: android, android-x86

I just installed Android x86 9.0 on a physical PC (i5 4th Gen).  I do not have a WiFi adapter for the PC.  I have it connected to my router using the LAN port.  How can I get this connected to my network?  I did not see anything in the setup.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Rodger

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ifconfig` to setup local network. I do not think that there is a UI for ethernet setup.
Please try the following commands:

```
ifconfig eth0 <free ip> netmask <netmask>
ifconfig eth0 up
```

you might also need to add your router as default route, you can do this by typing:

```
ip route add default via <gw ip> dev eth0
```

to access the terminal simply press `Alt+F1` - to get back to the UI `Alt+F7`

Answer (score 0):

Se soluciona, agregando en GRUB lo siguiente:

```
    EXTMOD=realtek VIRT_WIFI=0
```

Por ejemplo: En una maquina (dos sistemas operativos en una misma PC) con: Debian y Android, actualizar el Grub, desde Debian, asi:

0. Observar cuales son las condiciones iniciales, por ejemplo:

   ```
    hd0 es el disco duro: /dev/sda
    msdos2 es la particion 2: /dev/sda2
    android-9.0-r2 es la carpeta que crea el instalador de Android: /dev/sda2/android-9.0-r2
   ```
1. Añadir lo siguiente a /etc/grub.d/40_custom:

   ```
    menuentry 'My Android-x86' --class android-x86 {
    savedefault
    set root='hd0,msdos2'
    linux /android-9.0-r2/kernel quiet EXTMOD=realtek VIRT_WIFI=0 root=/dev/ram0 SRC=/android-9.0-r2
    initrd /android-9.0-r2/initrd.img
    }
   ```
2. Ejecutar, tambien desde Debian:

   ```
    sudo update-grub
    sudo grub-install /dev/sda
   ```
3. Verificar desde Android, use:

   ```
    ALT + F1 (Ir modo texto)
    cat /proc/cmdline
    ifconfig -a
    ALT + F7 (Retornar al modo GUI)
   ```
4. Revisar fuentes:

https://groups.google.com/g/android-x86/c/HznhzwaMAXk

http://git.osdn.net/view?p=android-x86/device-generic-common.git;a=patch;h=8ac9fea0db77ce1ace33e04a0da9def54a92ac55